# How to find a "short" walk that visits all vertices of a strongly connected directed graph

Tags: algorithms, directed-graphs, path

I am interested in the following algorithmic problem:
Given a strongly connected directed graph $G$, I want a "short" (see below for what I mean by short) walk that starts with an arbitrary vertex $s$ and contains all vertices of $G$.

Deciding if such a walk can be a path (i.e. no repeated vertices) is a well known NP-complete problem.

So I am interested in a walk that might repeat vertices.

I can perform the following:
Start with the walk $X=(s)$ and, until there are unvisited vertices, let $v$ be unvisited, take the last vertex $x$ from $X$ and append a $x$-$v$ path (it must exist because $G$ is strongly connected) to $X$. This procedure will eventually terminate, but will produce a walk of possibly quadratic length.

My question is, can we do better and guarantee a linear-sized walk? Is there an efficient (say linear or maybe $n\log n$) algorithm to compute the walk?

What I know: if G was undirected (and connected), there is always a walk visiting each vertex and it can be easily found by computing the spanning tree and doing DFS traversal of it, but this is not applicable since we assume $G$ to be directed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is **no**. For any $n\geq 3$ consider an oriented cycle $C_n$ and let $u\to v$ be adjacent in the $C_n$. Create $n$ vertices $x_1...x_n$ and add edges $u\to x_i$ and $x_i \to v$. Now any walk containing all vertices has length $\Omega(n^2)$.